# spring-data-elasticsearch with const_score

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to run the following query:

```
GET seg/seg/_search
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "iseg"
                }
            },
                "boost": 1.2
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't easily run this with spring-data-elasticsearch.

1. Is there any way to do this?
2. Are all the elasticsearch query DSL well supported by spring-data-elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes

Using Template :

```
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(constantScoreQuery(existsFilter("iseg")).boost(1.2f))
            .withIndices("seg")
            .withTypes("seg")
            .build();
    // when
    Page<SampleEntity> sampleEntities = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, SampleEntity.class);
```

Code copied and modified from [TemplateTest Class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplateTests.java)

Using Repository :

```
   SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(constantScoreQuery(existsFilter("iseg")).boost(1.2f))
            .withIndices("seg")
            .withTypes("seg")
            .build();
    // when
    Page<SampleEntity> page = repository.search(query);
```

Code copied and modified from [RepositoryTest Class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/support/SimpleElasticsearchRepositoryTests.java)

2) Yes Spring Data Elasticsearch uses QueryBuilder interface for dealing with all the Query DSL request for elasticsearch part.

Comment: thanks for your reply and great news.  I'm strange that why I can't find out "constantScoreQuery" in repo [spring-data-elasticsear] (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch). actually I run "grep -r constant *" under the directory of  spring-data-elasticsearch soruce code.

Comment: Yes i will add test cases to cover this. Thx

Comment: But when you use findByParameter1AndParameterTwo how to set this constant score? The query goes in query context not in filter context and still seems to calculate the score